# Как сделать кнопки в виде функции telebot

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Вот у меня есть функция, в которой содержится клавиатура. Как её присоединить к сообщению?

```
def setting():
  markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup() 
  btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Имя', callback_data='name')
  btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('ID', callback_data='id')
  markup.row(btn1, btn2)

  return markup


bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'Выберете что хотите настроить', reply_markup=setting())
```

Очень хочу оптимизировать код, но пока не получается

Comment: именно так, как вы и написали

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу смысла делать иначе

```
def setting(msg):
  markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup() 
  btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Имя', callback_data='name')
  btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('ID', callback_data='id')
  markup.row(btn1, btn2)

  bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'Выберите, что хотите настроить', reply_markup=markup)
```

Если ответ помог, просьба отметить его галочкой слева